# Openpyxl removes sorts that are already part of the excel file

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Right now, I am sorting data with pandas and then adding those values into the excel file and it works great. The problem is that the excel file already has the sort coded in and when I write data to the xlsx it will remove the sort. My colleagues want to be able to use the built-in excel sort and I can't figure out why openpyxl will remove that sort when I write data to the file.

Is there a parameter I'm missing or is this just how openpyxl operates? I can include code if it is needed.

Using the latest version of python and openpyxl.

Comment: openpyxl does not remove sorts. Please include the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on mac. Here is the code for writing from a dataframe to a sheet. Afterwards, the sheet will delete the pre-formatted sort in the .xlsx

```
def add_sheet(self, df, sheet, min_col, max_col, sheet_dim):
    index_positions = list(df.index.values)
    r = 1
    for x in index_positions:
        _row = df.loc[x].values
        c = min_col
        r += 1
        for val in _row:
            if c <= max_col:
                sheet.cell(row=r, column=c).value = val
                c += 1
```

Maybe it's how I save the excel file? Some parameter I'm missing?

```
test.save("test.xlsx")
```

Nevermind, here is code that will strip all sorts from my excel file on Mac.

```
test = test.load_workbook("test.xlsx")
test.save("test_save.xlsx")
```

The file goes from 376KBs to 259KBs. This doesn't make any sense.